How do I sign a transaction from React Native using WalletConnect?
I am designing a dApp using React-Native and Expo and want to enable users to sign and send transactions client-side.  So far, I have this:
try {
            const signedTx = await exportedProvider?.request({
                method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
                params: [txObject, senderAddress],
            });

            const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(`${signedTx.toString('hex')}`);
            console.log("successful transaction: ", receipt); 
} catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
}

exportedProvider?.request(...); causes my MetaMask wallet to open, but there is no prompt or anything asking me to sign/send the transaction, and the console never prints successful transaction.  However, it never prints an error either.  Is there a step I'm missing about prompting MetaMask to display a popup allowing me to agree to signing the transaction?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!
